# Multiple protractor configs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I'm new to protractor and created a protractor.config.js file and driving it with grunt. I would like to have multiple configurations for my protractor.config.js for different test sites but don't want to maintain multiple copies of a protractor.config.js as most of it is common. Is there a way to override the original one and just add what I care about eg multiCapabilities

Comment: Thanks @MichaelRadionov I think that is the path I should go down

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand your question correctly you want to run different flows i.e set of spec files with out making much changes to your config file?
if so 
replace your

```
specs: ['./example-spec.js'],
```

with

```
    suites: {
        ex_1: './example1-spec.js',
        ex_2: './example2-spec.js',
        ex_3: './example3-spec.js',
      },
```

say you want to run example 1 and example 3 spec you can do some thing like this

```
protractor yourConf.js --suite ex_1,ex_3
```

if you just say 
`protractor yourConf.js` all the test suits will run in sequence.